# how to refactor procedural code to mvc model?

Tags: python, user-interface, model-view-controller, bokeh

I have written a webapp which queries data from a database based on some inputs (start/end datetimes, machine id and parameter id) and shows it in a bokeh figure:

[image]

As you can see so far it works as intended but I have some plans to extend this app further:

1. Allow data from different batches (with different start/end timestamps) to be loaded into the same graph.
2. Perform some statistical analysis of the different batches, e.g. averages, standard deviations, control limits, etc.
3. Get live streaming updates of parameters for different machines and/or parameters.

So I am now at the point where the app starts to become more complex and I want to refactor the code into a maintainable and extensible format. Currently, the code is written procedurally and i would like to move to a MVC-like model to separate the data querying from the bokeh visualizations and statistical computations but I am unsure how to approach this best.

How can i refactor my code best?

```
import logging
import pymssql, pandas

from dateutil import parser
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

from bokeh import layouts, models, plotting, settings
from bokeh.models import widgets

SETTINGS = {
    'server': '',
    'user': '',
    'password': '',
    'database': ''
}

def get_timestamps(datetimes):
    """ DB timestamps are in milliseconds """
    return [int(dt.timestamp()*1000) for dt in datetimes]

def get_db_names(timestamps):
    logging.debug('Started getting DB names ...')
    query = """ 
        SELECT
            [DBName]
        FROM [tblDBNames]
        WHERE {timestamp_ranges}
    """.format(
        timestamp_ranges = ' OR '.join([f'({timestamp} BETWEEN [LStart] AND [LStop])' for timestamp in timestamps])
    )
    logging.debug(query)
    db_names = []
    with pymssql.connect(**SETTINGS) as conn:
        with conn.cursor(as_dict=True) as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            for row in cursor:
                db_names.append(row['DBName'])
    #logging.debug(db_names)    
    logging.debug('Finished getting DB names')
    return list(set(db_names))

def get_machines():
    logging.debug('Started getting machines ...')
    query = """
        SELECT 
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),[ID]) AS [ID], 
            [Name]
        FROM [tblMaschinen]
        WHERE NOT [Name] = 'TestLine4'
        ORDER BY [Name]
    """
    logging.debug(query)
    with pymssql.connect(**SETTINGS) as conn:
        with conn.cursor(as_dict=False) as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
    #logging.debug(data)
    logging.debug('Finished getting machines')
    return data

def get_parameters(machine_id, parameters):
    logging.debug('Started getting process parameteres ...')
    query = """
        SELECT
            CONVERT(VARCHAR(4), TrendConfig.ID) AS [ID],
            TrendConfig_Text.description AS [Description]
        FROM [TrendConfig]
        INNER JOIN TrendConfig_Text 
            ON TrendConfig.ID = TrendConfig_Text.ID
        WHERE (TrendConfig_Text.languageText_KEY = 'nl')
        AND TrendConfig.MaschinenID = {machine_id}
        AND TrendConfig_Text.description IN ('{parameters}')
        ORDER BY TrendConfig_Text.description
    """.format(
        machine_id = machine_id,
        parameters = "', '".join(parameters)
    )
    logging.debug(query)
    with pymssql.connect(**SETTINGS) as conn:
        with conn.cursor(as_dict=False) as cursor:
            cursor.execute(query)
            data = cursor.fetchall()
    #logging.debug(data)
    logging.debug('Finished getting process parameters')
    return data

def get_process_data(query):
    logging.debug('Started getting process data ...')
    with pymssql.connect(**SETTINGS) as conn:
        return pandas.read_sql(query, conn, parse_dates={'LTimestamp': 'ms'}, index_col='LTimestamp')
    logging.debug('Finished getting process data')

batches = widgets.Slider(start=1, end=10, value=1, step=1, title="Batches")

now, min_date = datetime.now(), datetime.fromtimestamp(1316995200)
date_start = widgets.DatePicker(title="Start date:", value=str(now.date()), min_date=str(min_date), max_date=str(now.date()))
time_start = widgets.TextInput(title="Start time:", value=str((now-timedelta(hours=1)).replace(microsecond=0).time()))
start_row = layouts.Row(children=[date_start, time_start], width = 300)

date_end = widgets.DatePicker(title="End date:", value=str(now.date()), min_date=str(min_date), max_date=str(now.date()))
time_end = widgets.TextInput(title="End time:", value=str(now.replace(microsecond=0).time()))
end_row = layouts.Row(children=[date_end, time_end], width = 300)

datetimes = layouts.Column(children=[start_row, end_row])

## Machine list
machines = get_machines()

def select_machine_cb(attr, old, new):
    logging.debug(f'Changed machine ID: old={old}, new={new}')
    parameters = get_parameters(select_machine.value, default_params)
    select_parameters.options = parameters
    select_parameters.value = [parameters[0][0]]

select_machine = widgets.Select(
    options = machines,
    value = machines[0][0],
    title = 'Machine:'
)
select_machine.on_change('value', select_machine_cb)

## Parameters list
default_params = [
    'Debiet acuteel',
    'Extruder energie',
    'Extruder kWh/kg',
    'Gewicht bunker',
    'RPM Extruder acuteel',
    'Temperatuur Kop'
]

parameters = get_parameters(select_machine.value, default_params)

select_parameters = widgets.MultiSelect(
    options = parameters,
    value = [parameters[0][0]],
    title = 'Parameter:'
)

def btn_update_cb(arg):
    logging.debug('btn_update clicked')

    datetime_start = parser.parse(f'{date_start.value} {time_start.value}')
    datetime_end = parser.parse(f'{date_end.value} {time_end.value}')
    datetimes = [datetime_start, datetime_end]

    timestamps = get_timestamps(datetimes)
    db_names = get_db_names(timestamps)

    machine_id = select_machine.value
    parameter_ids = select_parameters.value

    query = """
        SELECT
            [LTimestamp],
            [TrendConfigID],
            [Text],
            [Value]
        FROM ({derived_table}) [Trend]
        LEFT JOIN [TrendConfig] AS [TrendConfig]
            ON [Trend].[TrendConfigID] = [TrendConfig].[ID]
        WHERE [LTimestamp] BETWEEN {timestamp_range}
        AND [Trend].[TrendConfigID] IN ({id_range})
    """.format(
        derived_table = ' UNION ALL '.join([f'SELECT * FROM [{db_name}].[dbo].[Trend_{machine_id}]' for db_name in db_names]),
        timestamp_range = ' AND '.join(map(str,timestamps)),
        id_range = ' ,'.join(parameter_ids)
    )
    logging.debug(query)
    df = get_process_data(query)
    ds = models.ColumnDataSource(df)
    plot.renderers = [] # clear plot
    #view = models.CDSView(source=ds, filters=[models.GroupFilter(column_name='TrendConfigID', group='')])
    #plot = plotting.figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, x_axis_type='datetime')
    plot.line(x='LTimestamp', y='Value', source=ds, name='line')

btn_update = widgets.Button(
    label="Update", 
    button_type="primary", 
    width = 150
)
btn_update.on_click(btn_update_cb)

btn_row = layouts.Row(children=[btn_update])

column = layouts.Column(children=[batches, datetimes, select_machine, select_parameters, btn_row], width = 300)

plot = plotting.figure(plot_width=600, plot_height=300, x_axis_type='datetime')

row = layouts.Row(children=[column, layouts.Spacer(width=20), plot])

tab1 = models.Panel(child=row, title="Viewer")
tab2 = models.Panel(child=layouts.Spacer(), title="Settings")
tabs = models.Tabs(tabs=[tab1, tab2])

plotting.curdoc().add_root(tabs)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend OOP (Object Oriented Programming).
To do this you would need to:

1. Come up with a standardized object that is being graphed.  For
   example (Point:{value: x, startTime: a, endTime: y})
2. Extract obtaining the object (or list of objects) into a separate
   class/file (example found here: http://www.qtrac.eu/pyclassmulti.html)
3. Come up with a standardized interface. For
   example, the interface could be called 'Batch' and could have a
   method 'obtainPoints' that returns a list of 'Point' objects defined
   in step 1.

Now, you can create multiple Batch Implementations that implement the interface and the main class could call the obtainPoints method on the separate implementations and graph them.  In the end you would have 1 interface (Batch)  X implementations of Batch (ie. SQLDatabaseBatch, LDAPBatch, etc...) and a main class that utilizes all of these Batch implementation(s) and creates a graph.

Comment: I think it is a good idea to use a class for individual batches. Do you have any ideas how i can separate the visualization of the widgets from the rest?

Comment: I would recommend coming up with some sort of 'contract' Class (aka, a Controller in MVC terminology).  The view should only be responsible for painting.  The contract/controller would then be responsible for actions - listenening for UI events, data modification, etc...